# Numbers in Google fonts display different

Tags: css, fonts

I am using a Hebrew Google web font `notosanshebrew` it looks good except the numbers, when it comes to numbers it looks like a different font.

Is there any way to use other font when it comes to numbers or any other fix?

My import code for the font: 
`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css);`

Comment: The font has no numbers defined, so they will be displayed in the default font.

Comment: Ma kore! What @AntiHeadshot said. תגדיר פולבק פונט.

Comment: If my answer waas helpfull, please accept my answer (click on the tick below the up and down vote buttons at the top left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a fallback font behind your hebrew font.
In this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cksyaepa/) you can see the hebrew text (first one I got from google) in your given font and every other text is in Consolas (a monospace font).

css for the case the link breaks

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css);
body{font-family: 'Noto Sans Hebrew','Consolas';}
```