# Add numbers to Noto Sans font

Tags: css, fonts

Is there a way to add numbers to a Noto Sans font?

Accordingly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173592/numbers-in-google-fonts-display-different) question and more resources I read there are some fonts that dont have digits.

So how can I add digits? my font is `Noto Sans Hebrew` .

Thanks.

Comment: Itsik kapara neshama Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21646/is-it-possible-to-add-new-characters-to-a-font

Comment: toda raba gavar! Do you know other Hebrew font similar to Noto with digits?

Comment: Try this resource:
https://www.google.com/get/noto/